# Is there a better way to load a docx file from embedded resource?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, spire.doc

I'm recreating an old abandoned program that i created when i was learning c# which outputs a word file with the information from a form. The program extract the embedded resource which is template.docx located in Res folder to C:\ClearanceResource\template.docx then will be load by the program again using:

```
dox.LoadFromFile(@"C:\ClearanceResource\template.docx");
```

is there a better way to do this like getting the string location path of the embedded resource and using it in the `dox.Loadfromfile(someStringPath)` so that i dont need to create an instance of the file per run?

Comment: You don't have a path from an embedded resource but you certainly have a `Stream`

Answer (score 2):

Use [LoadFromStream](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/NET-Open-Word-Solutions-to-Open-Word-in-C-and-VB.NET.html) method.

```
Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("template.docx");
Document dox = new Document();
dox.LoadFromStream(stream, FileFormat.Docx);
```

Comment: @Arvie Delgado: can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57953815/visual-studio-c-loadfromremotesources regarding your Roro?